# Where is XMLEncryptionFactory?

Tags: java, xml, dom, encryption, cryptography

I was reading a tutorial about java encryption using the DOM, and I cam across a strange case of a package `javax.xml.crypto.enc.*` not existing. I had heard that not all packages were shipped with the standard JDK, and instead needing to be downloaded as separate modules and imported into the project, is this one of these cases? If so, where can I download it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did some research about the package, and it turns out that it was a part of, the now withdrawn, `JSR-106: XML Digital Encryption APIs`. http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=106